# Phase conversion of a depth map for its Fourier Transform

Tags: c++, math, fft

As is stated in [this paper](http://www.uv.es/~gpoei/eng/tri_op_im_rec.html) (jump to image of bear) and [this one](https://books.google.ch/books?id=nTknW4biqKgC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=phase+encoded+range+image&source=bl&ots=mjLFwnxFrb&sig=s2wEGqM6vy8vB7wr3-gU3Gm2tMQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKpqbcj6vMAhWHLsAKHXSuDqkQ6AEIPjAM#v=onepage&q=phase%20encoded%20range%20image&f=false), the Fourier Transform of a "phase converted" depth map (a picture where the luminosity of a pixel is related to its distance to the observer) should be translated left or right when the object is rotated along the vertical axis.

Consider these two examples (from link 1): on the left is the original depth map of the object, and on the right is the fourier transform of its "phase conversion"... as you can see, when the object is rotated, part of the FT is translated to the left, which is a very practical feature (see first link to understand why)...

[Example: http://www.androwing.com/webpix/a_09.gif](http://www.androwing.com/webpix/a_09.gif)

I've been trying to replicate this behaviour with mixed results .
First I needed to implement the formula of a "phase converted" depth map, which is given (see links) as a function Ph defined as

Ph[x,y]=exp(i*depth[x,y])

So obviously I had to turn it from exponential form to rectangular form, where

radius * exp(i * angle) -----> [radius * cos(angle),radius * sin(angle)]

Accordingly I modified my 2D FT application initialization from the standard

Fourier[i, j].real = (double)GreyImage[i,j];   // GreyImage: byte [0..255]

Fourier[i, j].imag = 0

to

double angle = (double)GreyImage[i, j];

Fourier[i, j].real = Math.Cos(angle);

Fourier[i, j].imag = Math.Sin(angle);

At first the results were encouraging... let's see an example (from the second link)

[Example2: http://www.androwing.com/webpix/orig_cube.jpg](http://www.androwing.com/webpix/orig_cube.jpg)

On the left is the depth map of the object, in the middle is its FT (magnitude), and on the right is the FT of its phase conversion where the 3 spots locate the center of 3 planar surfaces...

Now let's see what my results look like when using the above code...

[Example2: http://www.androwing.com/webpix/mytest.jpg](http://www.androwing.com/webpix/mytest.jpg)

As you can see, if the FT is remotely similar, the triangle on the right is inverted horizontally. This can be cured by inverting cos and sin...

Fourier[i, j].real = Math.Sin(angle);

Fourier[i, j].imag = Math.Cos(angle);

or by inverting the depth map...

double angle = 255.0 - (double)GreyImage[i, j];

but anyway, there is some mismatch around... now let's try with a [real depth map](http://www.androwing.com/webpix/rotation.jpg) (caution: picture NSFW but I didn't find any other example of multiple depth maps of the same rotated object)

[Example2: http://www.androwing.com/webpix/depth-map-test.jpg](http://www.androwing.com/webpix/depth-map-test.jpg)

In this case (which should have similar results as the bear example) my implementation of the phase conversion is completely wrong because the FT remains centered, and is not translated left or right by the rotation of the object.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong with my coding of the phase conversion ?

(I have tried pretty much everything imagination and desparation can dictate, like scaling the depth map to radians or using Math.exp in a any possible way... but without success)